# Stripping list brackets and replacing commas with spaces

Tags: python

It is my understanding that the `re` library only works for strings, while I have a list. The reason I ask is because I'm trying to convert this Python output to be compatible with r. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
1 2 3 4
```

What's tripping me up here is that I can't just say `output = 1 2 3 4`. I was thinking about trying to get around this by writing to file or something, but I don't know how to get my preferred output in the first place. Could someone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I feel it's unlikely you will get a useful answer until you can be more specific. Why does the re library even enter into this? If you really want a string, what's wrong with simply `str(list)`? Do you mean 'compatible with R' or is that a typo and you actually meant 'compatible with re'? Once you resolve those questions, what you actually want will be much clearer.

Comment: I just meant that I couldn't use `re`, and r isn't a typo. It's a programming language for statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Use join - and you will get what you want:

```
strToWrite = ' '.join(map(str, lVals)) #map will apply str to each element of lVals
```

Don't use 'list' as a variable name - it is not a very good practice since it reserved.